# NameError: name 'convert_symbol_to_int' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I've got an error: `NameError: name 'convert_symbol_to_int' is not defined` when I run this code:

```
class ReadData():
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)
        self.users = []

    def read(self):
        for row_index in range(2, self.sheet.nrows):
            rows = self.sheet.row_values(row_index)
            if rows[1] != '' and rows[2] != '' and rows[4] != '':
                woman = convert_symbol_to_int(row[8])
                man = convert_symbol_to_int(row[9])

   def convert_symbol_to_int(self,arg):
        if arg == '○':
            return 2
        elif arg == '×':
            return 1
        elif arg == '△':
            return 0
        else:
            return -1

x = ReadData('./data/excel1.xlsx')
x.read()
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens.
Why can't I access `convert_symbol_to_int`? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
man = self.convert_symbol_to_int(row[9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Kalyan Reddy already answered, you have to call the method with `self`, which is a pointer to the class itself. The following example shows the difference between externally declared functions and methods defined within the class:

```
def hello():
    print("hello, world!")


class Greeting(object):
    def __init__(self, world):
        self.world = world

    def hello(self):
        print("hello, {}!".format(self.world))

    def make_greeting(self):
        hello() # this will call the function we created outside the class
        self.hello() # this will call the method defined in the class
```

The purpose of `self` has already been explained in this question:
[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)